# Two angle of the triangle follow $3 \sin x - 4 \sin ^3x-k=0 $ ; what's the third one?

Tags: trigonometry

It is given the $A,B$ and $C$ are the angles of a $\triangle ABC$.
$\angle A >\angle B$ and both the angles follow the equation:

$3 \sin x - 4 \sin ^3x-k=0     $  ;             $k \in (0,1)$
and we have to figure out $\angle C$ out of the following options:

1.$\pi / 3$

2.$\pi /2$

3.$2\pi /3$

4.$5\pi /6$

The above equation just reduces to $$0 < \sin 3x < 1$$ 
Which in turn can reduce to $$0 < x < \pi /3$$ 
$$\Rightarrow 0 < \angle A, \angle B < \pi/3$$
 Now, due to such a wide range of angles, we can observe that $0 < \angle A + \angle B < 2 \pi/3$ which ultimately leads to more than one options being correct.

Kindly help me with this question.

Comment: You can also have $0<sin3x<1$ with an angle close to $\pi$ !

Answer (score 2):

If $0<\sin3x<1,$

$m360^\circ<3x<m360^\circ+180^\circ\iff m120^\circ<x<m120^\circ+60^\circ$ where $m$ is any integer

If $\sin3A=\sin3B$

$3A=n180^\circ+()^n3B$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies A=n60^\circ+(-1)^n B$

We have $0<A+B<180^\circ\  \ \ \  (1),0<A-B<180^\circ\  \ \ \  (2)$

As $A>B>0, n>0$

$n=1\implies A+B=?$

If $n=2, A-B=120^\circ,C$  can not be determined.

If $n=3,A+B=180^\circ$ which is impossible by $(1)$

Answer (score 0):

$$0<\sin 3x<1$$
Then $$0<3x<\frac{\pi}2 $$
$$0<x<\frac{\pi}6 $$
$$\Rightarrow 0 < \angle A, \angle B < \frac{\pi}6$$
$$\Rightarrow 0 < \angle A+\angle B < \frac{\pi}3$$
Then $\angle C>\pi-\frac{\pi}3=\frac{2\pi}3 \Rightarrow \angle C=\frac{5\pi}6$

Comment: What if $B=10^\circ, A=(120+10)^\circ$